# Looking to access wide angle camera of smartphone while making an AR application using Vuforia

Tags: android, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, vuforia

I am making an AR app using Vuforia engine and my project needs a greater FOV to track images. I figured if I access the wide angle camera of my android phone instead of low resolution one that
Vuforia accessed by default, my goal would be accomplished. So is there any way by which I can access the wide angle camera?

Currently by default lowest resolution camera is used by Vuforia for image tracking. I need to access wide angle camera.